# NetLogo: excluding items from a list after they have already been chosen

Tags: list, random, netlogo

I am using the setxy function to set the area that my turtles will be placed in. I made a list of the x values and y values. But I don't want more than 1 turtle at the same point. I'm not sure how to stop this from happening. This is the code that I am using for this:

```
create-vcells 20
   [ setxy one-of [0 0.6 1.2 1.8 2.4 3]
           one-of [0 0.6 1.2 1.8 2.4] ]
```

Does anyone have any insight? Thanks!

Comment: You can create all the possible x,y combinations, and then pick `n-of` them.

Comment: Didn't think about that! Thanks! I will try to do that. It will probably take a while to type all of the combinations.

Comment: Unless you know of a way to generate all of the possible x,y combinations from the lists that I have. What I put in the question was a short version of the list. I have about 55 in each list.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `vcells` is a breed.  I'll use regular `turtle` commands, but you'll be able to figure out how to adapt my examples to your code.

You can just use a double loop to look at each possible combination of x and y coordinates, putting the `create-` command inside the loops:

```
let xs [1 2 3 4]
let ys [10 15 20 25]

foreach xs [
  let x ?
  foreach ys [
    let y ?
    create-turtles 1 [setxy x y]
  ]
]
```

`foreach` loops through the items in a list (`xs` in the outer `foreach`, `ys` in the inner one).  Inside a `foreach` block, `?` refers to the current item from the list, and refers to each one in turn.  I assigned the value of `?` in the outer `foreach` block to a variable so that I could refer to its value from `xs` inside the inner `foreach` block, where `?` would refer to one of the elements of `ys` instead.  (Then I assigned the inner `?` to a variable as well just for the sake of clarity.)

If instead of every combination of coordinates, you just want to pair the x-coordinates and y-coordinates in order, you can use `foreach` with multiple lists:

```
(foreach xs ys [
  create-turtles 1 [setxy ?1 ?2]
])
```

Here `?1` refers to the current element from the first list (`xs`), and `?2` refers to the current element from the second list (`ys`).  Note that in this case you have to wrap the entire expression in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate n unique pairs of coordinates (contained in your two lists) as follows:

```
to-report n-pairs [#n #lst01 #lst02]
  let _n1 length #lst01
  let _n2 length #lst02
  let _nmax (_n1 * _n2) ;possible pairs
  if (#n > _n1 * _n2) [error "#n is too big"]
  let _idxs n-of #n n-values _nmax  [?]
  report map [(list 
      item int (? / _n2) #lst01
      item (? mod _n2) #lst02)
    ] _idxs
end
```